# charToDate(x) error when using "seqformat" in TraMineR

Tags: traminer

I'm using TraMineR to inspect work trajectories.

When using the `seqformat` function (from SPELL data) with `process = TRUE`, and an external data frame for `pdata`, as follows :

```
 situations <- seqformat(data[,1:4], id = 1, from = "SPELL", to = "STS",
                          begin = 3, end = 4, status = 2, right = NA, 
                             process = TRUE,  limit = 7644, pdata = pdata, 
                               pvar = c("id","birth"))
```

I get an error message :

**Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format**

I read many threads about that issue, but could not find any helpful solution.
Here are the structures of my data frames `data` and `pdata` :

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   2428 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ ID_SQ           : Factor w/ 798 levels "1","2","3","5",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 
...
 $ SITUATION       : chr  "En poste" "En poste" "En poste" "En poste" ...
 $ DATE_DE         : Date, format: "1997-09-01" "1999-05-03" "2003-01-01" 
...
 $ DATE_A          : Date, format: "1999-04-26" "2002-12-31" "2006-04-28" 
...
 $ SEXE            : Factor w/ 2 levels "Féminin","Masculin": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
...
 $ PROMO           : Factor w/ 6 levels "1997","1998",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ DEPARTEMENT     : Factor w/ 10 levels "BC","GCU","GE",..: 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 4 
4 4 ...
 $ NIVEAU_ADMISSION: Factor w/ 2 levels "En Premier Cycle",..: NA NA NA NA 
NA 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ FILIERE_SECTION : Factor w/ 4 levels "Cursus Classique",..: NA NA NA NA 
NA 4 4 4 4 4 ...


str(pdata)
'data.frame':   798 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ id   : Factor w/ 798 levels "1","2","3","5",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ birth: Date, format: "1997-01-01" "1998-01-01" "1998-01-01" "2000-01-01" ...
```

It seems to me that all date formats are OK.
But, clearly, something's wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Best,

Arnaud.

Answer (score 0):

The `seqformat` function expects integer values for the begin and end dates of the spells. Actually, these integers should be the (time-)position in the state sequence and will correspond in your example to column numbers in the resulting STS format.

So you need to transform your dates into integer values.

=============

The error

```
Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

occurs while the function tests whether `pdata` is the string `"auto"` with `if(pdata == "auto")`. This is because, when `pdata` contains dates, the test attempts to coerce `"auto"` into a date for the sake of comparison. The workaround is to input the dates as integers.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Gilbert. The weird thing is that, when keeping dates for "begin" and "end" arguments, but changing "pdata" to "auto" (and not specifying a value for "pvar") so that ages be computed using the start time of the first spell of each individual as her/his birthdate, the issue doesn't arise. So, I'm not sure that the issue comes from my date values for "begin" and "end" (?).

Comment: May be it works in some situation without raising an error. However, unexpected outcome could result because it will depend on how dates are coerced into integer values. Therefore, I strongly recommend to explicitly transform your dates into the wanted integer values (number of years, months, days, ... since the reference) before calling `seqformat`. The issue is not one of TraMineR, but of the coercion of dates into integer values.

Comment: @Arnaud I have now located where the error occurs and have added the explanation in the answer.

Comment: Hi Gilbert. Thank you for these additional information. I will transform my dates into integers. Afterwards, shall I keep the boolean "TRUE" for the argument "process"? Or shall I use "FALSE" ?

Comment: Depends on what you want. With `process=TRUE`, the outcome sequences will be aligned on ages (process duration since birth), while with `process=FALSE` they will be aligned on dates (position on the calendar time). If `TRUE` begin and end values are assumed to be dates when `pdata` is not `NULL`, and ages otherwise. If `FALSE`, begin and end values ares assumed to be dates when `pdata` is `NULL` and ages otherwise.

Comment: Thanks again Gilbert! Best,